# Best way to find the key to an entry by its value

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
const cOPE= { ADD:   43
            , SUB: 8722
            , MUL:  261
            , DIV:  247
            , EQU:   61
            , Point: 46
            , Clear: 99 
            }
```

and I currently use:

```
const kOPE = k => Object.entries(cOPE).find(o=>o[1]==k)[0]
```

to retrieve a key value based on a value.
example:

```
 console.log( kOPE(261) ) // -> MUL
```

Is there a better way to code the `kOPE` function?
 Isn't there simply a JS function that can return the name of a key?

[+] this code is internal in a closed object, other values cannot exist 
and each key is unique.

Comment: "Better" by which metric?

Comment: Potential issue with your current code is that an error will be thrown is nothing is found

Comment: @FelixKling I find my method a bit far-fetched, I wonder if there is not a JS method that does this directly ...

Comment: Get the list of key value pairs, find the one with the matching value, get the key.  What's far-fetched about that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance this code is internal in a closed object, other values cannot exist

Comment: If the object is static, you might consider constructing a reverse object - reverse the keys and the values, then just use ordinary property lookup

Comment: One small thing I might do, just because I like naming things, I might would deconstruct the find input to name them.  But that's just my personal flavor.  `Object.entries(cOPE).find(([key, value]) => value == k)[0];`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I thought about it, but I prefer to avoid multiplying objects. - Isn't there simply a JS function that can return the name of a key?

Comment: ¿What should happen if two keys have the same value? that might be a painful bug in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find yourself doing that often, you may want to consider inverting your map:

```
const invert =
  obj =>
    Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj)
        .map(([k, v]) => [v, k]));

const cOPE =
  { ADD:   43
  , SUB: 8722
  , MUL:  261
  , DIV:  247
  , EQU:   61
  , Point: 46
  , Clear: 99 
  };

const EPOc = invert(cOPE);

EPOc[261];
//=> MUL
```

---

**Performance**

If you do worry about performance, you should *definitely* use an inverted map.

Here's a curried version of `invert` that returns a function that accepts a value and returns the key associated to it. It's bound to the inverted object built from `obj`.

Using the same `test` function from Rick Hitchcock:

```js
const invert =
  obj => ((o, v) => o[v])
    .bind(null,
      Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj)
          .map(([k, v]) => [v, k])));

const cOPE =
  { ADD:   43
  , SUB: 8722
  , MUL:  261
  , DIV:  247
  , EQU:   61
  , Point: 46
  , Clear: 99 
  };


test(invert(cOPE), 43);
test(invert(cOPE), 261);
test(invert(cOPE), 99);
```

```html
<script>
// Credits to Rick Hitchcock for the test function
const test = (fnc, num) => {
  let j;
  console.time('speedTest')
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { j = fnc(num) }
  console.timeEnd('speedTest')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is much faster than yours (in Chrome at least):

```
const kOPE = k => Object.keys(cOPE)[Object.values(cOPE).indexOf(k)]
```

Even though objects are not guaranteed to be in order, I would assume `Object.keys` and `Object.values` would always be in the same order as each other.

**Comparisons:**

```js
const cOPE= { ADD:   43, SUB: 8722, MUL:  261, DIV:  247, EQU:   61, Point: 46, Clear: 99}
const kOPE1 = k => Object.entries(cOPE).find(o=>o[1]==k)[0]
const kOPE2 = k => Object.keys(cOPE)[Object.values(cOPE).indexOf(k)]

const test = (fnc, num) => {
  let j = fnc(num),
      timer = `${num} ${j}`;
  
  console.time(timer);
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    j = fnc(num)
  }
  console.timeEnd(timer);
}

console.log('Object.entries:')
test(kOPE1, 43);
test(kOPE1, 261);
test(kOPE1, 99);

console.log('_'.repeat(100))

console.log('Object.keys:')
test(kOPE2, 43);
test(kOPE2, 261);
test(kOPE2, 99);
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like @customcommander 's code is much faster than mine.

Comment: you can just use Console.time to perform performance tests  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time

Comment: Understood, good choice :)

Comment: Thanks for `console.time()`, wasn't aware of that function.

Comment: you're welcome, even if this post brought me very few points ...

Answer (score 0):

This way you can replace `null` by any initial state you want instead.

```js
const cOPE= { ADD:   43
            , SUB: 8722
            , MUL:  261
            , DIV:  247
            , EQU:   61
            , Point: 46
            , Clear: 99 
            }


const kOPE = k => Object
                    .entries(cOPE)
                    .reduce((obj, o)=>o[1]===k?o[0]:obj,null)
                    
console.log( kOPE(261) )

const test = (fnc, num) => {
  let j;
  console.time('speedTest')
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { j = fnc(num) }
  console.timeEnd('speedTest')
}

test(kOPE, 43);
test(kOPE, 261);
test(kOPE, 99);
```